# How to download a file located in web server CGI-bin folder?

Tags: python, mysql, perl, sqlite, cgi

I am creating a web application via **python cgi** . then after execute the cgi script , sqlite and mysql database files buildup in cgi-bin folder. thus i want to grant download it for users. but cgi-bin folder's files only for execute. so how can i do it?

which kind of **script** (php,perl,javascript,python etc.) can i use for **download** this generated database files in **cgi-bin**?

I haven't any experience with a real web hosting server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that with your cgi function. After you recieve a request you run that function:

```
import os
def return_file(name):
    filepath = os.path.join('/path/to/your/cgi-bin', name)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        return open(filepath, 'b').read()
```

It will return content of your file in binary mode and you'll can return it as any MIME-format you want.

Comment: can you introduce os module and isfile function?

Comment: is kinda standard shell utilits inside python. os.path.isfile is equal of shell's `[ -f /path/to/file ]` and os.path.join is a system independent way to get full path. Read more in python documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

Comment: Opss!! dear  senior_pimiento this script is working... but i want to client side script.this python script isn't match for my app.

Comment: I think you should describe more about your task with new question maybe

Comment: simple...i want to client side solution same as above python script.. Is it possible?

Comment: This is a terrible solution to an ill-thought-out problem. What if the user managed to set `name` to `../../../etc/passwd`?